# Voip solution for ubuntu family

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, voip

My question is: I need a VOIP solution to install on my xubuntu 12.10 machine (or maybe ubuntu) and **preferably with a detailed how-to configure it with images**! Wich one do you advise-me? (please notice that i need a **reliable** software)

Ps: please, no skype here! Just free and open source software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software that's free and works with Ubuntu and is in the software center is "Ekiga Softphone" if you go to their web site you will even get a free VIOP address so its free as air. They also have services that allow you to have a call in number if you want.

The site is here http://www.ekiga.org/